# How to convert color name to the corresponding hexadecimal representation?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hex

For example:

```
blue
```

converts to:

```
#0000FF
```

I wrote it as:

`Color color = Color.FromName("blue");`

But I don't know how to get the hexadecimal representation.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you're trying to do. Are you trying to dynamically figure out the hex value using C#? If that is the case, what format do you want it in? Decimal? As a String?

Comment: @Stargazer712: yes. as a string, something like: input:`blue` output:`#0000FF`

Comment: @Stargazer712 "hex representation" implies both hexadecimal and a string.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're half way there.  Use `.ToArgb` to convert it to it's numberical value, then format it as a hex value.

```
int ColorValue = Color.FromName("blue").ToArgb();
string ColorHex = string.Format("{0:x6}", ColorValue);
```

Comment: +1 I've realized my answer only works half the time, where this should be perfect.

Comment: It's not "perfect" since it yields "#FF0000FF" rather than "#0000FF". Also, local variables should not start with uppercase.

Comment: The leading `FF` is the alpha channel or opacity.  While that may not be relevant for HTML, it's perfectly legal in other situations.  You can remove it by using `ColorValue & 0xFFFFFF`.

Comment: If you intend to include alpha, then that should be x8, not x6.

Answer (score 5):

```
var rgb = color.ToArgb() & 0xFFFFFF; // drop A component
var hexString = String.Format("#{0:X6}", rgb);
```

or just

```
var hexString = String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", color.R, color.G, color.B);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{
    Color color = Color.FromName("blue");
    byte g = color.G;
    byte b = color.B;
    byte r = color.R;
    byte a = color.A;
    string text = String.Format("Color RGBA values: red:{0x}, green: {1}, blue {2}, alpha: {3}", new object[]{r, g, b, a});
```

// seriously :) this is simple:

```
    string hex = String.Format("#{0:x2}{1:x2}{2:x2}", new object[]{r, g, b}); 

}
```

Comment: each of color.G; color.B ; color.R and color.A contain the bytes, combine them as you see fit :) ...

string hex = String.Format("#{0}{1}{2}", new object[]{r, g, b});

Answer (score 3):

Ahmed's answer is close, but based on your comment, I'll just add a little more.

The code that should make this work is:

```
Color color = Color.FromName("blue");
string myHexString = String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", color.R, color.G, color.B);
```

Now you can do whatever you want with the string myHexString.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gplots` package:

```
library(gplots)
col2hex("blue")
# [1] "#0000FF"
```

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gplots/index.html

Inside `gplots` package the code for `col2hex` function is:

```
col2hex <- function(cname)
{
    colMat <- col2rgb(cname)
    rgb(
        red=colMat[1,]/255,
        green=colMat[2,]/255,
        blue=colMat[3,]/255
    )
}
```