# String color name to String Color Hex value in C#

Tags: c#, colors

i am trying to get the Hex value of color that is passed as string. for example,

```
private string HexColor(string colorName) // like "Red"
{

 // returns hex value like "12345"
}
```

i got links for convert a Windows.UI.Color to its Hex value. but not for a string color name to color hex value. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Update : For metro app

Comment: Metro, WPF, or Winforms?

Comment: I think you need this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336375/how-to-convert-color-name-to-the-corresponding-hexadecimal-representation

Answer (score 2):

[Color.fromName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname.aspx) creates a Color structure from the specified name of a predefined color, then [`ToArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.toargb.aspx):

```
Color.FromName(colorString).ToArgb().ToString("X8").Substring(2,6);
```

`ToString("X8")` creates the hexadecimal value as string from an integral type.

Answer (score 0):

```
Color c = Color.Red;
string hex = c.R.ToString("X2") + c.G.ToString("X2") + c.B.ToString("X2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
private string ConvertColorStringToHex(string colorString){
return Color.FromName(colorString).ToArgb().ToString("X8").Substring(2,6);
}
```