# Get hex codes for colors using Azure Cognitive Services Vision API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Is there a way to get hex codes for the dominant background and foreground colors from the Azure Computer Vision API? The color information in the default response looks like this:

```
"color": {
  "dominantColorForeground": "Black",
  "dominantColorBackground": "Black",
  "dominantColors": [
    "Black",
    "Grey"
  ],
  "accentColor": "7B5E50",
  "isBWImg": false
}
```

There's a hex code for the accent color, but does anyone know if there's a way to get hex codes for the other colors (specifically the dominant foreground and background colors)? I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa) but figured I might have missed something.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent provided directly by the API.

You can do it simply by code, for example in `C#` as mentioned in this topic: [How to convert color name to the corresponding hexadecimal representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336375/how-to-convert-color-name-to-the-corresponding-hexadecimal-representation)

```
int ColorValue = Color.FromName("blue").ToArgb();
string ColorHex = string.Format("{0:x6}", ColorValue);
```